# Populate an Excel Userform textbox using results of SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to populate a Userform using SQL when the user enters the Record Number.

[image: Userform]

```vb
Private Sub Enter_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sSQL = "SELECT ACCOUNT NAME,ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    sSQL = sSQL & "FROM SQL DATABASE"
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE RECORD_NBR = Record.txt"
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    rs.Open sSQL, cn
    AcctName.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NAME
    AcctNum.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NUMBER
    strConn = "Data Source=database;UID=1234;PWD=Password1;Database=SQL DATABASE"
    cn.Open strConn
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I receive Error 3907.

[image: Error 3907]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build your own Microsoft Access.  It might be time to consider making the switch.  For example, a form like this would be created with a few clicks, basically drag-and-drop, with no code, and Access managing the connection so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Before a connection can be used, it must be opened.  To resolve this issue, simply call the `cn` object's `Open` method - but you need a connection string to do that.

To have a robust application it's good practice to include an error handler to handle those situations where the database connection fails or the query fails.  Also, you should consider ensuring that the number of records returned is what you expect, and handle the cases where what's returned doesn't fit your expectation or requirement.

On to your code...you have a string named `strConn`, which looks like a connection string, but your code is a bit jumbled.  Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Enter_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String

    sSQL = "SELECT ACCOUNT NAME,ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    sSQL = sSQL & "FROM SQL DATABASE"
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE RECORD_NBR = Record.txt"

    strConn = "Data Source=database;UID=1234;PWD=Password1;Database=SQL DATABASE"
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.Open strConn
    rs.Open sSql, cn

    ' you may want code here to ensure that only one record was returned
    ' or perhaps you want to process multiple records

    AcctName.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NAME
    AcctNum.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NUMBER

    'Close the recordset
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    'Close the connection
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes. The first is that the connection has to be called first, then the recordset has to be loaded, and the sql syntax itself has a problem.

```vb
Private Sub Enter_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sSQL = "SELECT ACCOUNT NAME,ACCOUNT NUMBER " '<~~ Space is required.
    sSQL = sSQL & "FROM SQL DATABASE " '<~~ Space is required.
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE RECORD_NBR ='" & Record.txt & "' " '<~~Record.txt is variable
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    strConn = "Data Source=database;UID=1234;PWD=Password1;Database=SQL DATABASE"
    cn.Open strConn
    rs.Open sSQL, cn
    AcctName.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NAME
    AcctNum.Text = rs.Fields!ACCOUNT NUMBER
    strConn = "Data Source=database;UID=1234;PWD=Password1;Database=SQL DATABASE"
    cn.Open strConn
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```